# Изображение в Base64 строку

Tags: javascript, изображения, base64

У меня есть файл и путь к нему (абсолютный). Пытаюсь внутри Снап (Snap.berkeley.edu) используя только Javascript, получить base64 строку этого файла. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти правильный вариант решения.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Base64

Comment: картинку загрузите в canvas и получите base64 через метод toDataURL(). https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: у меня нет канваса и html, все проиходит через javascript

Comment: @GioDosSantos ну так сделайте канвас в js, выполните манипуляции и удалите его

Answer (score 0):

```
import fs from "fs";
const imgFile = "путь файла";
const fileinBase64 = fs.readFileSync(imgFile, { encoding: "base64" });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]